How can I anchor a yard shed without damaging the concrete slab?
I'm getting a 8x12 shed and the property owner doesn't want the concrete pad damaged. Is there a way to put it on the concrete pad without anchoring it to the concrete?

Its possible, please post dimensions and photos

What are the dimensions of the slab?

It is entirely possible. How depends on some missing information.
If it has a floor, ( plywood or OSB),  You can attach 4x4s horizontally to the underside of the flooring. At the outer edges and every 24 inches should do it. ( Depending on the weight of what you are storing inside, you may need to go to every 16 inches.) Then the unit sits on the 4x4s on the concrete pad.
If the unit does not have a floor, build a deck to the dimensions of the unit. Again 4x4 and plywood or deck boards can be used. Then attach the shed to the deck.
In both instances, if needed a ramp can be built by the door to allow easier entrance.
One of the unknowns here is your location and the likelihood of strong winds.
If you are in an area where that is likely, the shed should be anchored to the concrete pad. If the park does not allow that they are being very shortsighted, but you must comply.

The local winds is the most important information the OP can give.

If high winds are a problem, and the shed is very firmly connected to the 4x4s, could the 4x4's be extended so they go beyond the edges of the concrete pad, then use high-wind ground screws or trailer tiedowns to hold down the 4x4's? If so, and the extended 4x4's are a tripping hazard, the whole deck could be extended to fully cover the concrete pad in at least one dimension of the shed, use the tie downs to lock down the deck, and the shed would have a porch, too.

@Triplefault, great solution.  I would use that if I was in the OP situation.
